# How much engineered "sand" I would need to build an Orbital Tower that reaches the ISS?

Tags: physics, engineering, space-constructs, construction

Well, I do know that there are questions about space towers that have already been asnwered, however, none of them with today's technology, such as **engineered sand**.

"Sand Castle Holds Up A Car! - Mechanically Stabilized Earth":
https://youtu.be/0olpSN6_TCc

Basically, engineered sand is just a bunch of sand or dirty that has layers of materials that helps giving it strength. Like a sand sandwich.

I know it would be more efficient to make a tower with regular materials, such as concrete and steel. But these materials are expensive and wouldn't be able to support such massive building, and the other problem (one of many of them) is that the building has to put columns piercing the ground in a depth equivalent of the height of said structure.

So, the ISS is 400 km from earth, and the tallest building still to this day is just 800 meters tall, the Burj Khalifa. If a 400 km building had to excavate that far, it would enter the mantle.

Well, the idea behind using engineered sand or earth is that it is a cheap material and fairly available. And the idea is to use different types of materials in differents heights. Making a weird looking pyramid or mountain. And no, the tower wouldn't be occupied, it would be a solid structure.

In such, the first layers would be sand or dirty and the material used to make the plates would be recycled plastic. In taller layers, the materials would increasingly more resistant with other types of engineering processes, like piercing the lower layers with columns made of aluminium, concrete, steel and if it isn't high enough, carbon fibers.

I know it is an ambitious and insane construct, but if it can reach the ISS station instead of a 36.000 km normal space elevators requite. Then, maybe it would be feasible

Comment: Burj Kalifa does *not* have excavation through the mantle.  The mantle is a minimum of bout 20 km deep, at the thinnest points of the crust, and by your own "rule" Burj only needs about 800 m excavation.

Comment: @ZeissIkon , fixed. And also, it is not "my own rule", it is a common engineering requirement to put colums under the building in order to keep it stable.

Comment: I strongly suspect that such a construct, if it were possible (it didn't collapse due to the weakness of the reinforcing material), would cause some sort of seismological devastation on a continental scale. Far smaller buildings stress the tectonic plates/faults they stand on/near. The size of this pyramid is such that it could very well cause the plate to fracture and start subducting.

Comment: FYI the ISS is not geosynchronous, so you couldn't build a tower to it.  I assume you just mean you want a tower of equivalent height.

Comment: @workerjoe Yes, just a tower of equivalent height in the proper place (be it on the equator or other place on the earth.

Comment: ISS and other satellites should take care to avoid this tower at all costs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compressive strength of "constrained" sand or clay is limited by the tensile strength of the constraining material -- if you build a column of sand constrained by wet craft paper (i.e. a grocery bag, of the old style) it will be barely if any stronger than mere wet sand; if you build one held together by a steel tube, the tube will let the sand approach the compressive strength of the material of the grains (though the steel tube itself will also contribute some strength).

However, there's a **MUCH** larger problem with an orbital tower to 400 km height: velocity.  A classic tower runs to and past geosynchronous, so that in fact it *hangs* from a counterweight that's moving faster than orbital speed at its height; this gives access to geosynchronous orbit by simply "stepping off" the tower at the correct height.

If your tower is only 400 km tall, by contrast, orbital velocity will be something like 7 km/s relative to the top of the tower (which is moving only at ground speed, around 1600 km/hr at the equator).  Even worse, the ISS is in an inclined orbit (around 53 degrees, as I recall, to make it accessible from Baikonur without excessive delta-V requirement to change plane), so you'd only ever be close to it once or twice a day, as your tower rotated under the orbital plane (and likely much less frequently than that, since the ISS orbit isn't resonant with the Earth's rotation).

In the end, even if it were physically possible to build a compression-loaded tower 400 km tall (it isn't, with any known material, never mind sand), it wouldn't be of any use for launching to any orbit of any kind, and would instead pose a hazard to anything in an orbit lower than the tower's top.

Comment: Just because you're not at orbital velocity at the top of a 400km high tower, it doesn't mean that it is _pointless_ launching from that altitude. You can neglect aerodynamic drag for a start, which is a non-trivial portion of a rocket's delta-V budget (and fairings aren't light, either).

Comment: @StarfishPrime Oh, yeah, but you have to haul about 85% of an orbital rocket up to the top of your tower, and your launcher has to be (near) vertical because your rocket will be fighting its own weight when it starts.  Build a **BIG** linear accelerator up there, maybe, but you might as well build that going up a mountain in Ecuador.  Not to mention your ground crew working in space suits.  Better off just launching from Ecuador in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

### None...

To paraphrase a line from the movie *The Graduate,* "I have one word for you... just one word... *erosion."*

Reinforced dirt (aka "engineered sand"), which is used for basically every modern bridge construction on the planet, is not at all magic. It's a convenient way to fill large volumes of space in a way that's structurally stable — but it isn't used for tall things (that I know of) for a number of reasons.

The biggest is that for any kind of height (like the 5-10 meters needed for the average bridge) you need to retain the soil behind some kind of wall (aka "retaining wall"). If you don't, wind and water will erode it away a lot more quickly than you might think. In fact, I can't think of any soil wind can whip away faster than sand, reinforced or not.

*Many rural bridges only use retaining walls right up against the roads they cross over. Given the right kind of soil and the available space for a slope, it's cheaper to plant grass and other plants to stop erosion than to build a wall. But anywhere where you'll have, give or take, less than ~30° of slope off the side of the bridge road, you'll see a retaining wall.*

That means you need a giant retaining tube holding all that sand in for the sake of your space elevator. A tube that needs all the same engineering solutions that the very same space elevator built without the sand would require.

So, my answer is "none," because I can't see how it's a practical solution to the problem of space elevators.

---

*Just to add an opinion, most practical application of science is driven by economics, not the science. At this time it's hard for me to swallow even the possibility of actually building a space elevator. It's like owning a ginormous piece of mining equipment. The cost of ownership is so large that if you can't keep that bounder operating CONSTANTLY you can't afford to own it. And I can't see that need compared to rocket fuel, which is comparatively as cheap as water. The need to constantly be moving people or materials into orbit would suggest a pre-existing infrastructure. In other words, off-world mining or space docks or a Donald-Trump's-Ego-Sized hotel would have to justify the elevator. And even then, so long as rocket fuel is cheaper than building and maintaining that elevator, the elevator will never come to pass. Just my two cents....*

Answer (score 2):

You would need to make the base a bit wider than the peak.

Let's see.... a pile of "engineered sand", 400km up from sealevel.
Hmmm, subsidence.
400 km, 1m2, would mass about 920000 tonnes.
Hmm. Compression of lower segments.
hmm, depression of crust into mantle.
factor gravitational gradient....

Your pile would need to have a diameter of approximately.... five time around the Earth.

I.E.
If you want to pile up sand to reach the ISS, you will have to BUILD UP THE WHOLE EARTH SURFACE that high.
You might get away with having one location be about 35km higher than the other side of the world.
Anything higher just depresses the crust deeper into the mantle, and gets you nowhere.

Sorry.

Comment: Floating fundament in magma - cooling it for energy and making it float by gas under presure bubbles in the fundament part of thing, gigalions of pascals. May u include taper calculations in the answer? For a good case something like 300MPa basalt thing which we have a planet

Comment: @MolbOrg **none** of those things qualify as "engineered sand" as per OP. Unless you include hyper-pressure metamorphic processing, effectively making your own granite. And that would *still* not be able to reach 400km. Refer the various questions in here about tallest possible mountains on Earth.

Comment: "include hyper-pressure metamorphic processing" obiviously I do, there is no way it not happening in 400+ km tall structure of any kind and material. Tallest mountain has few problems, one is stability over time of more than million years, meaning if u build 20km mountain it won't srink to 11km one over a year or over a night. Second, at some point it will sink, also not necessarly a fast process, and there is no constructed solution to negate that in a _natural_ one, while for _artificial_ one we may consider some options. But first thing first, do we have sufficient footprint for if all good

Comment: But okay, do not mind, taper ratio won't do here, angle of repose is what it needs here, with sand 30-45 degree may be doable, then it looks you ovrestimated diameter signifiantly, that was the thing which caugth my eye

Answer (score 2):

### Sand isn't cheap enough

Sand is about \$50 per tonne, let's assume it is 1 cubic meter (average density as sand pile and a cheaper place)

Then a cubic km of sand worth is \$50 billion per km3.

There are numbers for sand about its [Angle of repose](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_repose) be 34-45 degree, so in a good case we talk about footprint to be a circle with radius 400km. Good case also may include some reinforcement, but at some point only interal friction matters.

Volume of that sand-tower-cone will be about 67 million cubic km, or \$3.35e18 or about 3 million of trillions. Transporing cost is not included.

To shave transporting costs and necessity to pay to some strangers, use magma "bricks", which is as good as sand at that scale, just toss them in a pile, probably some dodecahedron shapes or maye irregular ones, available at any place and is capable to provide you with some energy - extract magma, it flows on its own once hole is dug, cast bricks, put them in a heat exchanger, make steam and rotate your turbines, will provde energy for your building equipment.

### feasibility

Compressive problems are a bit different from tensile strength problems, as one fails in all sorts of different ways while the other just snaps. So as you can iso-press a material with quite a force and it is very hard to break it in that way, not impossible, but pressure is far suoerior number towhat we may see for tensile strengths(different beasts in some way but yeah....)

So using sand or any other available material for building a high cone isn't insane and is feasible to some extend. We do not live in 2 km high pyramids because we have better and cheaper ways for our needs, but it does not mean we can't build few km pyramid with some space inside it, and bringing highest skyscraper into the fight is not reasonable, if we do not understand where and why the limits for it come from.

Breaking continental plate is a possible outcome, those are quite fragile, around 8MPa if I recall correctly, tensile strength. (If one needs the place where it comes, I can dig it out on a request, not so convinient to do so atm)

So the construction on that scale needs under crust part of construction, which can float in magma and be constantly cooled, which can be used as energy source as well.

To keep with the pressure at depths of titanic proportions, we can form voids filled with gases under appropriate pressure or other low athomic mass materials, water one of those.

So it is, probably, possible to make some structure which can float in magma and will support weight of that tip of iceberg, 60 percent of which may be under crust in magma.

### Efforts can be better spent

If we look at proportions of the work involved, so as engenering involved, so as effects on the planet, using any other material available which may slash the mass of the construction 3-4-5 orders of magnitude may be a better idea, even if it costs 5 million per tonne.

40-80 km cone tower is as good as 400km one

There are non rocket launch systems on wiki, and some are even quite feasible, like lanch loop, it has it's share of problems but still.

If we like to mess with magma then making  shaft to stick a guss gun like launch system it may be a bettr idea.

Sooo your typical space program looks like a cheap toy compared to sand pyramid, so one can go with it as well, if it is on the table as option.

Orbital ring can be built on fraction of those efforts and porovde a better convinience, and do not stress a planet.

So yeah, there are many directins with look more attractive, if they are available for some civilisation or organism.